# How to delete image from firebase storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, flutter-web

I am building a flutter web app, and I have a button which clears the firebase storage.
This is the code I am trying to use for this:

```
final FirebaseStorage storage =
      FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: 'gs://oras-99e16.appspot.com');


  Future<void> clearStorage() async {
    List<String> url = [];
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection("events")
        .getDocuments()
        .then((value) => value.documents.forEach((element) {
              url.add(element.data["coverImageUrl"]);
            }));
    for (int i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
      await storage.ref().child(url[i]).delete();
    }
  }
```

I already store all the Urls in the 'events' firestore collection. When I run it I get this error: Overflow on channel: plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage.  Messages on this channel are being discarded in FIFO fashion.  The engine may not be running or you need to adjust the buffer size if of the channel.
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method StorageReference#delete on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage)

Comment: I find it unlikely that you're not getting an error. Firebase storage doesn't have an official implementation for flutter web and unofficial ones don't have the same syntax as your implementation.

Comment: Isn't this the implementation for web: firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start? And you were right, I get this error: Overflow on channel: plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage.  Messages on this channel are being discarded in FIFO fashion.  The engine may not be running or you need to adjust the buffer size if of the channel.
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method StorageReference#delete on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage)

Comment: That's the javascript implementation. Not flutter web. You could use that JS implementation, but it's definitely not what you're doing here.

Comment: And what could I do? the uploads work perfectly

Comment: You could use the [firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase) package. Or use the JS implementation you show and do dart-js interop.

Comment: And how can I do that? sorry, I am new to firebase and flutter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220617/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-bennett567).